# Calling malloc and storing return value in double pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
char **init(int n) {
    char **result;
    result = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    return result;
}
```

I need help understanding whether the 3rd line is a bug or not. The call to malloc() will create N contiguous blocks on memory on the heap each big enough to store a single character, and it will return a void ptr (base address of the array). However, result is a pointer to a pointer, so it would need to store the address of another pointer which is not the case here?

Comment: Why is the result a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @merlin2011 If you see in the method we declared the variable result to be a double pointer which is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: It's likely a bug, but I don't understand your reasoning.

Comment: @aDabOfRanch, Declaring `result` to be a `char**` means that `result` is syntactically a `char**`, but it doesn't mean that it is semantically a `char**`. The return value of `malloc` is a linear block of memory, not an array of pointers.

Comment: One call to `malloc` creates one contiguous block of storage

Comment: So if I did result = malloc(n * sizeof(char*)); that would be valid?

Comment: @aDabOfRanch Sure (assuming `n` is neither negative nor too big).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking to do something like this:

```
char *init(unsigned int n) {
    char *result;

    /* allocate the memory */
    result = malloc(n * sizeof(char));

    return result;
}
```

this will allocate memory to store n contiguous characters.

you could reduce the code to:

```
char *init(int n) {
    return malloc(n * sizeof(char));
}
```

or instead of calling this function you could just directly do:

```
malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

or you could create a macro

```
#define INIT_CHAR_ARR(n) malloc((n) * sizeof(char))
```

if you want n contiguous character pointers:

```
malloc(n * sizeof(char*))
```

It would help us help you if you explained your end goal, maybe there is a better way to do what you are doing.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's good practice to use a `sizeof()` when using `malloc()` to clearly state what the returned value is being used for and why we are allocating that number of bytes. `malloc(n)` is less informative to the programmer then `malloc(n*sizeof(char))`, the latter helps explain we are using this as an array of n characters.

Comment: I strongly disagree. If you wrap it in a macro (or function), the name already provides that information. If you call malloc directly to initialize a variable, you can just do `char *result = malloc(n * sizeof *result);` (which is correct no matter the type of `result`). In neither case do you need to write `sizeof (char)`.

Comment: Yes many ways to do this, using `sizeof()` is key in both. I live in the embedded systems world where it is pretty standard to write the data type in `sizeof()` rather then the variable name (probably relates to keeping strict track of memory) but anything works as long as you keep it consistent